# Allow only certain domains being able to load an iFrame

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I'm building some widgets for a charity. Due to some logo licensing malarkey, I've got to find some way of only allowing white-listed sites from running the code, or to send a error message (or something like that) rather than the widget.

We've got to use iFrames as a fair few sites have already embedded them.
Ideally, a PHP solution would be best, but JS is ok if needs be.

***So, the one liner; Can I check the domain the iFrame is sitting in and send it different content?***

I wonder what the chances are of being able to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the HTTP_REFERER header.

```
<?php

$allowed_domains = array(
        'a-good-domain.com',
        'another-nice-one.org',
        );

$allowed = false;
foreach ($allowed_domains as $a) {
    if (preg_match("@https?://$a/.*@", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $allowed = true;
    } 
}

if ($allowed) 
    echo "Nice domain";
else
    echo "Ugly domain";
```

Comment: You should really use a hash for this. No need to loop over `$allowed_domains` that way.

Comment: Can HTTTP_REFERER header be spoofed? If yes, relying on this header wouldn't be safe.

Comment: This solution would only work for one page load. The moment you do something within the iframe (change page) the referer will be app itself, not the one that hosts the iframe.

Comment: @ramkumar Referer header spoofing requires actions from the user herself.  I can make requests to a server with a spoofed Referer header, but I cannot make someone else's browser send a forged header.

Comment: @MikeGarcia You can also whitelist the hosted domain itself.  Any further navigation is thus allowed.

Comment: @MikeGarcia Sorry, misread the question.  But you can set a cookie or use query parameters to keep the state during navigation and provide different content.